# include .js file in ajax file

Tags: php, ajax

I am making an application with PHP. There is a listing page of products containg the name of manufacturer, name of product, address etc. each with edit option. When a user edits the particular record, through the ajax, I have made it so that each field can be edited from a textbox.  In order to accomplish this, my ajax code echoes all of the fields as textboxes with the current value.  Also, I have included the js files in that ajax file (i.e. `<script type="javascript" src="pathname"></script>`  But due to this the design of the page on Mozilla it is changed, but on Chrome it is fine. So, how could I include these js file in ajax file, so that design would not be changed on any browser?

thanks.

Comment: We need to see some of the source code or a URL to clarify the issue as your description is quite vague.

Comment: Ajax is just a part of JavaScript... I don't think we can help you without the source code. Post it on Pastin or something.

Comment: How does the design of the page get changed by including another file?

Answer (score 0):

I ncluding external javascript file cannot change the view itself unless you have made some html changes in the javascript itself.

Try not to include javascript files in the ajax response, include the required files when complete html page is loaded and execute javascript functions after you get the ajax response.